# Ruby on Rails full application template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I would like to create Rails **application template**, so when I run `rails new` it should:

- override Gemfile (add gems, remove gems and those shitty comments etc.)
- convert application layout file to HAML and edit its content
- edit assets files to import bootstrap-sass files as required
- edit and set my database variables in database.yml
- maybe something else, dunno atm...

I just want it to be ready to go, I hope you can understand me so far.

**How could I achieve this?**

I know about rails composer, but I don't want to choose from these application templates, I want the one with constant set of tools I always use. I can commit new application to GitHub and then just run `git clone` on it each time with just changing my new project name, but is it the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the awesome Rails feature [**Rails Application Templates**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html), `rails new project_name -m /path/to/template.rb`

[`Here is my own template`](https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/f1c4c5207fe20c98573c):

```
# minitest, capistrano, pry
gem_group :development do
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'capistrano',         '2.15.5'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
  gem 'pry-rails',          '~> 0.3.2'
end

gem_group :test do
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'ffaker', require: false
end

run "bundle install"

#install minitest test_helper
generate 'mini_test:install'

environment "config.generators do |g|\n      g.test_framework :mini_test, spec: true, fixture: true\n    end"

#Add pride to minitest config
run "sed -i '' '4 s#^#require \"minitest/pride\"#' test/test_helper.rb"

#create postgres DB in postgresql 
#development and test
run "psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE #{app_path}_development;'"
run "psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE #{app_path}_test;'"

#add database yml
run "sed -i '' '4 s#^#require \"minitest/pride\"#' test/test_helper.rb"

#Add minitest features to Rake task
run %q^echo 'MiniTest::Rails::Testing.default_tasks << "features"' >> Rakefile^

#Fix README.md
run "rm README.rdoc"
run "touch README.md"

#Initialize local Git repository and Initial Commit
git :init
git add: "."
git commit: "-a -m 'Initial commit :pray:'"
```

Comment: It still isn't a solution for editing some files as I said, am I right? I would like to automatically remove some content from Gemfile, routes file and layouts.

Comment: i edit many files here and  automatically remove some content, add files, remove junk e.t.c. Read  Rails Application Templates guides, it's build on top of [Thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor), so you can make any manipulation with files as you want